# Нужны кавычки или все-таки нет?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Нужны кавычки?

> Я думаю, что, если я отвечу «да» / да, она обидится, а если «нет» / нет — тоже обидится.

А здесь?

> Здесь не принято говорить «здравствуйте» / здравствуйте и другую такую чушь, как, например, «до свидания» / до свидания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы **везде** поставила кавычки.

По принципу единообразия: если в предложении слово "да" (или "здравствуйте") написано в кавычках, тогда и "нет" (или "до свидания") — тоже в кавычках.

• Первое предложение я бы оформила так (без повтора "я"):
*Думаю, что, если я отвечу «да», она обидится, а если «нет» — тоже обидится.*

•• Во второе предложение я бы добавила усилительную частицу "же":
*Здесь не принято говорить «здравствуйте» и другую такую же чушь, как, например, «до свидания».*

> [**Примечание.**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159) Подлинные выражения (цитаты), вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится...

Из Нацкорпуса:

*Ты на привязанность меня решил купить и полагаешь, что я теперь **отвечу «да»**?* (С. А. Самсонов. Ноги);
*Я понял: если я сейчас **скажу «нет»**, Тамара повернется и уйдет, а у меня будет нехорошо на душе и я не смогу работать* (Виктория Токарева. Пираты в далеких морях);

*Не может же, думала, Епишкин в его-то возрасте не знать, что принято **говорить «здравствуйте»**...* (Наталия Ермильченко. Привет);
*Хотелось бы **сказать «прощайте»**, но приходится **говорить «до свидания»*** (Максим Милованов. Рынок тщеславия).

*— Здравствуйте! —

Что особого тем мы друг другу сказали?

Просто **«здравствуйте»**, больше ведь мы ничего не сказали.

...

— Здравствуйте! —

Был ведь, был ведь прекрасный обычай у русских

Поклониться друг другу при встрече

(Хотя бы совсем незнакомы)

И **«здравствуйте»** тихо сказать.*

Владимир Солоухин. [Здравствуйте](https://www.culture.ru/poems/23204/zdravstvuite)